# PySpark Dataframe Transformation pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a below dataframe which i need to transform as below.

i am using PySpark 3.4.1 .

```
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID                     |SH                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|64ecb76b5e6452.63046706|[{"AJ":0,"BW":888300,"CA":0,"CF":0,"DT":25,"EP":378368,"ML":76.0,"FP":{"AD":44098,"DD":46,"NA":44098,"NW":46},"NJ":{"FD":26,"PL":6,"TH":0.0}},{"AJ":0,"BW":887749,"CA":0,"CF":0,"DT":25,"EP":438380,"ML":72.0,"FP":{"AD":44106,"DD":46,"NA":44099,"NW":46},"NJ":{"FD":25,"PL":5,"TH":0.0}},{"AJ":0,"BW":870441,"CA":0,"CF":0,"DT":25,"EP":498392,"ML":67.0,"FP":{"AD":44098,"DD":46,"NA":44098,"NW":46},"NJ":{"FD":26,"PL":6,"TH":0.0}},{"AJ":0,"BW":875936,"CA":0,"CF":0,"DT":25,"EP":558404,"ML":74.0,"FP":{"AD":44099,"DD":46,"NA":44099,"NW":46},"NJ":{"FD":25,"PL":5,"TH":0.0}},{"AJ":0,"BW":878518,"CA":0,"CF":0,"DT":23,"EP":618417,"IL":62.288616,"ML":82.0,"FP":{"AD":44105,"DD":49,"NA":44105,"NW":49},"NJ":{"FD":25,"PL":5,"TH":0.0}}]|
+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

i am creating this dataframe (spark streaming job) after consuming from Kafka and using json_get_object function to get ID and SH    from json object

now i need to transfomrm as below.

```
+----+-----------------------+----+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|EN  |ID                     |EP  |SH_AJ|SH_BW   |SH_CA|SH_CF|SH_DT|SH_EP  |SH_FP_AD|SH_FP_DD|SH_FP_NA|SH_FP_NW|SH_NJ_FD|SH_NJ_PL|SH_NJ_TH|
+----+-----------------------+----+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|null|64ecb5227ecfe0.13927687|null|0.0  |674969.0|0.0  |0.0  |25.0 |78727.0|44099.0 |45.0    |44099.0 |45.0    |21.0    |1.0     |0.0     |
+----+-----------------------+----+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|null|64ecb5227ecfe0.13927687|null|0.0  |674969.0|0.0  |0.0  |25.0 |78727.0|44099.0 |45.0    |44099.0 |45.0    |21.0    |1.0     |0.0     |
+----+-----------------------+----+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|null|64ecb5227ecfe0.13927687|null|0.0  |674969.0|0.0  |0.0  |25.0 |78727.0|44099.0 |45.0    |44099.0 |45.0    |21.0    |1.0     |0.0     |
+----+-----------------------+----+-----+--------+-----+-----+-----+-------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

i have tried explode and explode_outer tried other stuff as well but i am not able to explode json array.

this is the acutal JSON whhich i am getting from Kafka.

```json
{
   "ID":"64ecb76b5e6452.63046706",
   "SH":[
      {
         "AJ":0,
         "BW":888300,
         "CA":0,
         "CF":0,
         "DT":25,
         "EP":378368,
         "ML":76.000000,
         "FP":{
            "AD":44098,
            "DD":46,
            "NA":44098,
            "NW":46
         },
         "NJ":{
            "FD":26,
            "PL":6,
            "TH":0.000000
         }
      },
      {
         "AJ":0,
         "BW":887749,
         "CA":0,
         "CF":0,
         "DT":25,
         "EP":438380,
         "ML":72.000000,
         "FP":{
            "AD":44106,
            "DD":46,
            "NA":44099,
            "NW":46
         },
         "NJ":{
            "FD":25,
            "PL":5,
            "TH":0.000000
         }
      },
      {
         "AJ":0,
         "BW":870441,
         "CA":0,
         "CF":0,
         "DT":25,
         "EP":498392,
         "ML":67.000000,
         "FP":{
            "AD":44098,
            "DD":46,
            "NA":44098,
            "NW":46
         },
         "NJ":{
            "FD":26,
            "PL":6,
            "TH":0.000000
         }
      },
      {
         "AJ":0,
         "BW":875936,
         "CA":0,
         "CF":0,
         "DT":25,
         "EP":558404,
         "ML":74.000000,
         "FP":{
            "AD":44099,
            "DD":46,
            "NA":44099,
            "NW":46
         },
         "NJ":{
            "FD":25,
            "PL":5,
            "TH":0.000000
         }
      },
      {
         "AJ":0,
         "BW":878518,
         "CA":0,
         "CF":0,
         "DT":23,
         "EP":618417,
         "IL":62.288616,
         "ML":82.000000,
         "FP":{
            "AD":44105,
            "DD":49,
            "NA":44105,
            "NW":49
         },
         "NJ":{
            "FD":25,
            "PL":5,
            "TH":0.000000
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add the schema of the "first" dataframe ? the one with 2 columns (ID, SH)

Comment: i have not create StructSchema. I am using below function to get ID and SH .
`df = spark.readStream format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers"......) .load()`
`outstream = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")`
`json_df = outstream.select(#session common keys from all the json
                               get_json_object(col("value"),"$.ID").alias("ID"),\
                               get_json_object(col("value"),"$.SH").alias("SH"))`

Comment: please add `json_df.printSchema()` to your question.

Comment: where does  `EN` comes from ?

Comment: There are multiple packets coming from Kafka, in this one there is no EN key. so it can be null

Comment: Then you probably need to add it to the schema when parsing the json. And all other optionnal fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Current situation

The schema of your dataframe seems to be only strings.

```
df.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  ID|                  SH|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|[{"AJ":0,"BW":888...|
+--------------------+--------------------+


df.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SH: string (nullable = true)
```

Therefore, you need to input a schema to be able to do anything with your data.

### Definition of the schema

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

schema = T.ArrayType(
    T.StructType(
        [
            T.StructField("AJ", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("BW", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("CA", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("CF", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("DT", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("EP", T.IntegerType()),
            T.StructField("IL", T.FloatType()),
            T.StructField("ML", T.FloatType()),
            T.StructField(
                "FP",
                T.StructType(
                    [
                        T.StructField("AD", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField("DD", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField("NA", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField("NW", T.IntegerType()),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
            T.StructField(
                "NJ",
                T.StructType(
                    [
                        T.StructField("FD", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField("PL", T.IntegerType()),
                        T.StructField("TH", T.FloatType()),
                    ]
                ),
            ),
        ]
    )
)
```

### Parse JSON string with the schema

```py
df.withColumn("SH", F.explode(F.from_json("SH", schema))).select("ID", "SH.*").show()

+--------------------+---+------+---+---+---+------+---------+----+--------------------+------------+
|                  ID| AJ|    BW| CA| CF| DT|    EP|       IL|  ML|                  FP|          NJ|
+--------------------+---+------+---+---+---+------+---------+----+--------------------+------------+
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|  0|888300|  0|  0| 25|378368|     null|76.0|{44098, 46, 44098...|{26, 6, 0.0}|
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|  0|887749|  0|  0| 25|438380|     null|72.0|{44106, 46, 44099...|{25, 5, 0.0}|
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|  0|870441|  0|  0| 25|498392|     null|67.0|{44098, 46, 44098...|{26, 6, 0.0}|
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|  0|875936|  0|  0| 25|558404|     null|74.0|{44099, 46, 44099...|{25, 5, 0.0}|
|64ecb76b5e6452.63...|  0|878518|  0|  0| 23|618417|62.288616|82.0|{44105, 49, 44105...|{25, 5, 0.0}|
+--------------------+---+------+---+---+---+------+---------+----+--------------------+------------+
```

Comment: this is working. but if i want to break FP and NJ also into column again.

Comment: @VirendarKumar do you really need me to do all the job ? I used `"SH.*"` to break `SH`. So if you use the same logic : `"SH.NJ.*"`, `"SH.FP.*"`

Comment: No @Steven, Thank you for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("SH", F.explode(F.col("SH")))

df_transformed = df.select(
    F.lit(None).alias("EN"),
    "ID",
    F.col("SH.EP").alias("EP"),
    F.col("SH.AJ").alias("SH_AJ"),
    F.col("SH.BW").alias("SH_BW"),
    F.col("SH.CA").alias("SH_CA"),
    F.col("SH.CF").alias("SH_CF"),
    F.col("SH.DT").alias("SH_DT"),
    F.col("SH.EP").alias("SH_EP"),
    F.col("SH.FP.AD").alias("SH_FP_AD"),
    F.col("SH.FP.DD").alias("SH_FP_DD"),
    F.col("SH.FP.NA").alias("SH_FP_NA"),
    F.col("SH.FP.NW").alias("SH_FP_NW"),
    F.col("SH.NJ.FD").alias("SH_NJ_FD"),
    F.col("SH.NJ.PL").alias("SH_NJ_PL"),
    F.col("SH.NJ.TH").alias("SH_NJ_TH")
)

df_transformed.show()
```